# Bash command that iterates throught folder and runs python script

Tags: bash, scripting

i am trying to run linux command to run python script:

```
for f in /mnt/data/service/fmriprep/geht/sub-P*; do (python 2_correlation.py -i 
"$f" -o /mnt/data/service/corr_graph/correlation_P*.csv )
```

my python script takes as input file in -i directory and return as -o a new .csv. I expect to return correlation_P* for each folder P* (P001, P002, P*) to this path (/mnt/data/service/corr_graph/correlation_P*.csv with the same P001,P002, P*), but stucked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great thanks to @glenn jackman, you raised my skill. So command which worked for me is:

```
for dir in /mnt/data/service/fmriprep/geht/sub-P*; do if [ -d "$dir" ]; then  
num=${dir##*P} && python 2_correlation.py -i "$dir" -o 
"/mnt/data/service/corr_graph/correlation_P${num}.csv";fi done
```

Answer (score 2):

For each iteration of the loop, you need to extract the digits after "P" and use them in the csv file name:

```
in_dir=/mnt/data/service/fmriprep/geht
out_dir=/mnt/data/service/corr_graph

for dir in "$in_dir"/sub-P*; do 
    num=${dir##*P}
    python 2_correlation.py -i "$dir" -o "$out_dir/correlation_P${num}.csv"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! it should be "$in_dir": python 2_correlation.py -i "$in_dir" -o "$out_dir/correlation_P${num}.csv"
done?

Comment: You tell me: is the argument to `-i` supposed to be "/mnt/data/service/fmriprep/geht" or "/mnt/data/service/fmriprep/geht/sub-P001"? The former is "$in_dir" the latter is "$dir"

Comment: -i supposed to be an /mnt/data/service/fmriprep/geht/sub-P001, so $dir is

Comment: I have one more question i also have .html files in in_dir, how could i filter it (i dont need to iterate iover them)?

Comment: before the `num=` line, put `[ -d "$dir" ] || continue` to validate that $dir is a directory.

Comment: it worked now with: `for dir in /mnt/data/service/fmriprep/geht/sub-P*; do if [ -d "$dir" ]; then  num=${dir##*P} python 2_correlation.py -i "$dir" -o "/mnt/data/service/corr_graph/correlation_P${num}.csv";fi done`
but it always write new return of `2_correlation.py` to last num